# Consistency in $_GET

Tags: php

Is there a good way to keep consistency in the `$_GET`

For example if i have a url
`http://www.example.com/index.php?Id=5&sort=new`

And i want to now add a new `$_GET` field at the end of that so is there any way i can create a function that will keep the `Id` and `sort` and add my new var `lim`?

So the URL Now looks like: `http://www.example.com/index.php?Id=5&sort=new&lim=100`

maybe something like:

```
add_new_get('http://www.example.com', 'lim=100');
```

Im sure i can come up with a function but just wondering if someone has implemented such thing that they would like to share :D

Comment: @Artelius, No i could do it by sessions but then i have to control the setting and unsetting of each type of session and that will involve me in a whole reem of long hours. Just a simple function that will pick up the Current Gets and then add my new one would be great :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could always just do `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'&yourstuff=whateves';` I guess you could wrap that in a function if you really wanted to.

the above includes everything before the file name. if you want ONLY the get requests you can do:

```
$new_req = "?";
foreach ($_GET as $key=>$val){
    $new_req .= "&".$key."=".$val;
}
$new_req .= $your_new_value;
```

Answer (score 2):

You might find it preferable to use a class to manage your query string handling rather than writing your own.

See [HTTPQueryString](http://jp.php.net/manual/en/class.httpquerystring.php)

It isn't terribly complex to write a function to take a url and build your query string, but with a class like HTTPQueryString, you don't have to worry about making sure you have the right encoding, tests for whether there are already variables present in the string, etc.

**Edit**

e.g.

```
$query = new HttpQueryString(false, 'Id=5&sort=new');
$query->mod('lim=100');
echo $query->toString(); // echoes http://www.example.com/index.php?Id=5&sort=new&lim=100
```

Comment: Ty for the solution, im liking this HTTPQueryString :D

Comment: it's a fairly robust solution. As a bonus, used as a singleton, all classes relying on it can work on the same query string, adding their own parameters as necessary and never needing to worry about what other classes do with it. Obviously, you'd need to take steps to avoid collisions, though.

Comment: as an addendum to my last comment, you might want to write a wrapper class for it anyways, just in case you might later want change how your GET variable management is handled

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more hackish solution is to use [output_add_rewrite_var](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.output-add-rewrite-var.php) and [output_rewrite_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.output-reset-rewrite-vars.php)